# How to display the layers of a pretrained model instead of a single entry in model.summary() output?

Tags: keras, tf.keras, keras-layer

As the title clearly describes the question, I want to display the layers of a pretained model instead of a single entry (please see the `vgg19 (Functional)` entry below) in `model.summary()` function output?

Here is a sample model that is implemented using the `Keras Sequential API`:

```
base_model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights=None, input_shape=(32, 32, 3), pooling='max', classes=10)
model = Sequential()
model.add(base_model)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1_000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

And here is the output of the `model.summary()` function call:

```
Model: "sequential_15"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
vgg19 (Functional)           (None, 512)               20024384  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_15 (Flatten)         (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_21 (Dense)             (None, 1000)              513000    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_22 (Dense)             (None, 10)                10010     
=================================================================
Total params: 20,547,394
Trainable params: 523,010
Non-trainable params: 20,024,384
```

**Edit:** Here is the `Functional API` equivalent of the implemented `Sequential API` model - the result is the same:

```
base_model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(32, 32, 3), pooling='max', classes=10)

m_inputs = Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
base_out = base_model(m_inputs)
x = Flatten()(base_out)
x = Dense(1_000, activation='relu')(x)
m_outputs = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inputs=m_inputs, outputs=m_outputs)
```

Comment: If you want to flatten a pre-trained model layers, into your model, you should force tf to go through pretrained model layers while it is creating your model. How to do that? Well, you should add it as input or output in your model definition line. Then, for creating connections between your input layer and output layer, it has to go through internal layers, otherwise it will considers it as a single layer in your new model.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `Sequential`, I tried using the [Functional API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional) i.e. the `tf.keras.models.Model` class, like,

```
import tensorflow as tf

base_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights=None, input_shape=(32, 32, 3), pooling='max', classes=10)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()( base_model.output )
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1_000, activation='relu')( x )
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')( x )

model = tf.keras.models.Model( base_model.input , outputs )
model.summary()
```

The output of the above snippet,

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         [(None, 32, 32, 3)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 32, 32, 64)        1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 32, 32, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 16, 16, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 16, 16, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 16, 16, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 8, 8, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 8, 8, 256)         295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 8, 8, 256)         590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 8, 8, 256)         590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 4, 4, 256)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 4, 4, 512)         1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 4, 4, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 4, 4, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 2, 2, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 2, 2, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 2, 2, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 2, 2, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 1, 1, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling2d_2 (Glob (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1000)              513000    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 10)                10010     
=================================================================
Total params: 15,237,698
Trainable params: 15,237,698
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Many thanks for your care. Please see the edited OP as I provided the `Functional API` equivalent of my `Sequential API` model and the result is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding after going through the docs and running a few tests (via TF 2.5.0) is that when such a model is included in another model, Keras conceives of it as a "black box". It is not a simple layer, definitely no tensor, basically of complex type *tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional*.

I reckon this is the underlying reason that you can not print it out in a detailed way as part of the model summary.

1. Now, if you'd like to just review the pre-trained model, have a sneak peak etc., you can simply run:

```
base_model.summary()
```

or after constructing your model (sequential or functional, doesn't matter at this point):

```
model.layers[i].summary() # i: the index of your pre-trained model
```

If you need to access the pre-trained model's layers, e.g. to use its weights separately etc., you can access them with this way as well.

---

2. If you'd like to print the layers of your model **as a whole**, then you need to trick Keras into beliving the "black box" is no stranger but just yet another KerasTensor. In order to do that, you can wrap the pre-trained model in another layer -in other words, connect them directly via Functional API-, which was suggested [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68463550/12852066) and has worked fine for me.

```
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()( base_model.output )
```

---

I don't know if there is any specific reason that you'd like to pursue the new input route as in...

> m_inputs = Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
>
> base_out = base_model(m_inputs)

Whenever you locate the pre-trained model in the middle of your new model, as coming after the new Input layer or adding it to a Sequential model per se, the layers within would disappear from the summary output.

Generating a new Input layer or just feeding the pre-trained model's output as input to the current model didn't make any difference for me in this case.

Hope this clarifies the topic a wee bit more, and helps.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want to do

```
base_model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights=None, input_shape=(32, 32, 3), pooling='max', classes=10)

model = Sequential()

for layer in base_model.layers:
   layer.trainable = False
   model.add(layer)

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1_000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```